# username and password in Qrcode with django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple qr scanner and qrcode in python. This opens a website after scanning.
What i want: the django username and password in a qrcode. So the user scans the qr and logs in.
I dont know how to convert the password of the user because of the hash.

Here is the code for creating the qrcode (from model).

```
def create_Qrcodes(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
            url = the url to go to after scanning the qrcode
           
            new_qrcode = Qrcodes.objects.create(vacature=instance)
            qrcode_img = qrcode.make(url + str(instance.id) + "/")
            new_qrcode.url_vacature = url + str(instance.id) + "/"
            new_qrcode.save()

            canvas = Image.new('RGB', (600,600), 'white')
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
            canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
            random_nummer = random.randint(10000000, 90000000)
            fname = f"{new_qrcode.id}{random_nummer}.png"
            buffer = BytesIO()
            canvas.save(buffer, 'PNG')
            new_qrcode.image.save(fname, File(buffer))
            canvas.close()
```

So what i want is an qrcode of the username and password.

Comment: If the password is stored as a hash then I believe you can't get the text of it, all you can do is take a string, hash it and see if it produces the same hash (which is how you check if the user entered the correct password)

Comment: ok, thats an idea. Do you know how i can hash a string.

Comment: You can use something like hashlib to hash strings (guide [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/)) but how can you use that to login, you'll need the plain text of the password to login no?